# Search value in php array and get all keys

Tags: php, arrays, search

Is there any better (= quicker ) solution to get all keys of value in array than foreach loop with if?

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple',
'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');
```

print_r($array); will give me:

```
Array ( [0] => apple [1] => orange [2] => pear [3] => banana [4] => apple [5] => pear [6] => kiwi [7] => kiwi [8] => kiwi )
```

array_search("kiwi", $array); will give me **6**

But I want all keys of kiwi. So I want **6,7,8**. In this case.

Bruteforce search loop:

```
 $searchObject = "kiwi";
 $keys = array();
 foreach($array as $k => $v) {
 if($v == $searchObject) $keys[] = $k; 
}
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Alternatively, you could also use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) in this case, and providing the second parameter as **needle**:

```
$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');
$searchObject = 'kiwi';
$keys = array_keys($array, $searchObject);
print_r($keys);
```

Would yield something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 8
)
```

[Sample Output](https://tehplayground.com/JOrRRT9VRA7Bxu2W)

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_search_values( $m_needle, $a_haystack, $b_strict = false){
    return array_intersect_key( $a_haystack, array_flip( array_keys( $a_haystack, $m_needle, $b_strict)));
}

$array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple',
'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');

print_r( array_search_values( 'kiwi', $array,true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<?php
    $array = array('apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple','pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi', 'kiwi');
    $count = count($array);
    $str_to_search = 'kiwi';
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        if($array[$i] == $str_to_search){
            echo $i.",";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: is that quicker solution? i dont think so