# PHP - APRIORI - How to display a combination that meets the support value?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to display a combination value that is more than the support value, suppose the support value 4 then that will be displayed only a combination of more than 4.
I attach the code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $item1; $i++) 
{
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $item2; $j++) 
    {
        $hasil = 0;
        $item_pair = $item[$i].'|'.$item[$j];
        $item_array[$item_pair] = $hasil;
        foreach($belian as $item_belian) 
        {
            if((strpos($item_belian, $item[$i]) !== false) && (strpos($item_belian, $item[$j]) !== false)) 
            {
                $item_array[$item_pair]++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of the above code, which in the red line there is still a combination value that is less than the value of support, how to prevent the combination is not displayed.

Result

[image]

Comment: It might be useful to see what you inputs are as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quicker solution, I believe you can use [array keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to return all the keys in the $item_array which have value less than support value. Just place this after you finished assigning values to the array.

```
$support_value = 4 // this is just for an example, use your own value.
$keys = array_keys($item_array, $support_value); // to get all the item pair that has value < support value

// to delete all the item pair that has value < support value
foreach($keys as $key){
    unset($item_array[$key]);
}
```

Source: [Search value in php array and get all keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144492/search-value-in-php-array-and-get-all-keys)

Comment: Just put the code after you finish assigning values to $item_array. I've edited my answer